# Storing duplicate data in hdf5 files

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm using H5py and numpy to manipulate HDF5 files.  I want to expose two views of the same data, with different metadata.  The approach I'm trying is to store a reference to the 1-dimenstional array rather than duplicating its data.

I have a number, `num_observers`, of 1-dimensional data streams in the form of an array with `num_samples` values (e.g. temperature readings from a thermometer).  I store each data stream as a dataset, with the stream's metadata as the dataset's attributes.

In some circumstances, I want to read all the streams as an `num_observers`-dimensional array dataset, with metadata that is different from the metadata of the individual streams.

```
    num_observers = get_num_observers()
    num_samples = get_num_samples()

    with h5py.File(filename, "w") as f:
        grp_observations = f.create_group("observations")
        grp_indiv = f.create_group("observations/as_individual")

        grp_ndarray = f.create_group("observations/as_ndarray")
        dset_ndarray = grp_ndarray.create_dataset(
            "observation_ndarray", (num_observers, num_samples), dtype="float"
        )

        set_dset_ndarray_metadata()
        
        observer_ids = get_sorted_observers()
        for observer_index, observer_id in enumerate(observer_ids):
            observer_data = get_data_stream(observer_id)
            observer_metadata = get_metadata(observer_id)

            latest_individual_dataset = grp_indiv.create_dataset(
                observer_id, data=observer_data, dtype="float"
            )
            set_latest_individual_dset_metadata(observer_metadata)

            #Here is where I want the data to be referenced, rather than duplicated
            dset_ndarray[observer_index] = latest_individual_dataset
```

I think that I am following the example of creating a hard link, as described in the H5py documentation (https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/group.html), but the size of the resulting file is twice as big as when I create only the individual data streams.

Is the problem that `dset_ndarray` gets assigned a size when created, and that size isn't affected by the subsequent use of hard links?  How can I store these two views of the data without doubling the file size?

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved the result I wanted by using a virtual dataset. (https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/vds.html)

The resulting files use more space than the individual observations alone, but much less than fully duplicating the values.

Here is the revised code:

```
num_observers = get_num_observers()
num_samples = get_num_samples()
layout = h5py.VirtualLayout(shape=(num_observers, num_samples), dtype="float")
with h5py.File(filename, "w") as f:
    grp_observations = f.create_group("observations")
    grp_indiv = f.create_group("observations/as_individual")

    grp_ndarray = f.create_group("observations/as_ndarray")

        
    observer_ids = get_sorted_observers()
    for observer_index, observer_id in enumerate(observer_ids):
        observer_data = get_data_stream(observer_id)
        observer_metadata = get_metadata(observer_id)

        latest_individual_dataset = grp_indiv.create_dataset(
            observer_id, data=observer_data, dtype="float"
        )
        layout[observer_index] = h5py.VirtualSource(latest_dataset)
        set_latest_individual_dset_metadata(observer_metadata)

    dset_ndarray = grp_ndarray.create_virtual_dataset(
            "observation_ndarray", layout
            )
    set_dset_ndarray_metadata()
```

Comment: Yes, a virtual dataset is the way to go. (I was working on a solution when you posted this.) :-) Question: you have `layout[node_index]` but `node_index` is not defined. Is that supposed to be `layout[observer_index]` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right! That code has the symbol misnamed.  I will edit the answer.